# Calculate Similarities between two arrays of different scales

Tags: similarity, recommendation-engine

In creating a content-based recommender, I have several binary measurements, combined with integer measurement values and I wish to compare the two vectors.

For example, consider the following two users and traits t1 - t5, where the traits could be, for example:

- meets_requirement1
- meets_requirement2
- meets_requirement3
- years_experience,
- years_college

`... [  t1   t2   t3   t4   t5]`

```
User1   0    1    1   18    4
User2   1    1    1   15    2
User2   1    1    0    4    8
```

The data are (clearly) not Gaussian across rows. How do I compute similarity scores between these users? Do I need to normalize down traits first?

I'm looking for a result like the following (in Python, just to show the result. I don't need it in Python.):

```
a = array([[0, 1, 1, 18, 4],
[1, 1, 1, 15, 2],
[1, 1, 0, 4, 8]])

print squareform(1 - pdist(a, metric='cosine')) 
print squareform(1 - pdist(a, metric='correlation'))
print squareform(1 / (1 +  pdist(a, metric='euclidean')))
```

Yielding the output:

```
[[ 0.     0.994  0.627]
 [ 0.994  0.     0.566]
 [ 0.627  0.566  0.   ]]

[[ 0.     0.991  0.384]
 [ 0.991  0.     0.273]
 [ 0.384  0.273  0.   ]]

[[ 0.     0.211  0.064]
 [ 0.211  0.     0.074]
 [ 0.064  0.074  0.   ]]
```

But I want to be sure I'm not over emphasizing the t4 & t5 values.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use either **metric** for your application. At least the data doesn't suggest a particular one.

More important is the **normalization**. You need to define, *how many years of, e.g., more experience are equivalent to how many years of college* etc. (These are the normalization coefficients you need to define.)

Consider the following three users:

```
UserA   1    1    1   10    5
UserB   1    1    0   10    5
UserC   1    1    1   10    4
```

Who is more similar to `UserA`: `UserB` or `UserC`? It clearly depends on some semantic knowledge and not on the numbers alone.

And if one user has two times more experience, is he twice as good? (This question relates to the metric. But it's probably not that crucial.)

Note that `correlation` and `cosine` actually apply a normalization. But this is not suited for elements with different semantics. `correlation` will shift both vectors to an equal average and scale them to have equal dispersion. But this way you mix *years* and boolean entities.